# Simple adventure game producing wrong output, no errors when compiling

Tags: java

I don't receive any errors when compiling, however the output isn't correct?
The program stops when the user should able to input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class person
{
    private String name, choice1, choice2, choice3;

    //Getters
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getChoice1()
    {
        return this.choice1;
    }
    public String getChoice2()
    {
        return this.choice2;
    }
    public String getChoice3()
    {
        return this.choice3;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setName( String n )
    {
        this.name = n;
    }
    public void setChoice1( String c1 )
    {
        this.choice1 = c1;
    }
    public void setChoice2( String c2 )
    {
        this.choice2 = c2;
    }
    public void setChoice3( String c3 )
    {
        this.choice3 = c3;
    }
}
public class AdventureGame
{
    public static void main(String[] Args) throws Exception
    {
        String end = "Game Over";
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        person p = new person();
        //intro
        System.out.println( "Welcome travellar, your adventure awaits you..." );
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.print( "Player Name: " );
        String inputName = keyboard.next();
        p.setName(inputName);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Question 1
        System.out.println( "You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go \"upstairs\" or into the \"kitchen\"?" );
        String inputChoice1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        p.setChoice1(inputChoice1);

        if ( p.getChoice1().equals("kitchen") )
        {   //Q2
            System.out.println("There is a long countertop with dirty dishes everywhere. Off to one side there is, as you'd expect, a refrigerator. You may open the \"refridgerator\" or look in a \"cabinet\" ");
            String inputChoice2 = keyboard.nextLine();
            p.setChoice2(inputChoice2);
            if ( p.getChoice2().equals("refridgerator") )
            {
                System.out.println("Inside the refridgerator you see some food. Would you like to eat that food? (\"yes\" or \"no\")");
                String inputChoice3 = keyboard.nextLine();
                p.setChoice3(inputChoice3);
                if ( p.getChoice3().equals("yes") )
                {
                    System.out.println(p.getName() + " died of food poisoning.");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.print(end);
                }
                else if ( p.getChoice3().equals("no") )
                {
                    System.out.print("You will never know what that food tasted like. The regret haunts you till suicide.");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.print(end);
                }
            }
            else if ( p.getChoice2().equals("cabinet") )
            {   
                System.out.println( "The cabinet was a trap! You took a barbed contraption to the face; you are blinded and bleeding out." );
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("As you lie on the floor blind and bleeding out, you hear footsteps. Do you \"move\" or try to \"hide\"?");
                String inputChoice3 = keyboard.nextLine();
                p.setChoice3(inputChoice3);
                if ( p.getChoice3().equals("move") )
                {
                    System.out.print("As you moved faster so did the footsteps. you took a final blow.");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.print(end);
                }
                else if ( p.getChoice3().equals("hide") )
                {
                    System.out.println("blinded, you failed to realise that you were in plain sight. You became an easy meal.");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.print(end);
                }


            }

        }
        else if ( p.getChoice1().equals("upstairs") )
        {
            System.out.println("As you reach the top of the stairs, your encounter 3 doors; which door do you enter? (\"1\" or \"2\")");
            String inputChoice2 = keyboard.nextLine();
            p.setChoice2(inputChoice2);
            if ( p.getChoice2().equals("1") )
            {
                System.out.println("As you grab the handle of the first of the door you hear a scream!");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("do you \"run\" or \"open\" the door?!");
                String inputChoice3 = keyboard.nextLine();
                p.setChoice3(inputChoice3);

                if( p.getChoice3().equals("run") )
                {
                    System.out.println("Running down the stairs, you misplaced a foot and fell to your demise.");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.print(end);
                }
                else if (p.getChoice3().equals("open"))
                {
                    System.out.println("As your head poked through, an unrelenting force slammed the door, decapitating your head.");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.print(end);
                }
            }
            else if ( p.getChoice2().equals("2") )
            {
                System.out.println("You enter what seems to be a vacant bedroom. Do you take a nap? (\"yes\" or \"no\")");
                String inputChoice3 = keyboard.nextLine();
                p.setChoice3(inputChoice3);
                if ( p.getChoice3().equals("yes") )
                {
                    System.out.println("You never wake up...");
                    System.out.print(end);
                }
                else if ( p.getChoice3().equals("no") )
                {
                    System.out.println("You turn around turn around to leave bu the door is gone?!");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println( "The grim reaper appears... Your time has come." );
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.print(end);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There might be some confusion about the use of `next()` and `nextLine()`.

1. For `next()`, you are scanning the input until the next space and you place the cursor at the position in which the scanning stopped
2. For `nextLine()`, you are scanning the input until the end of the line and you place the cursor on a new line.

***Disclaimer***: Before you continue reading on and look at the proposed the solution, you can try and figure out what's wrong with your code by using the above information and see if you can solve it yourself! :)

So the slight *bug* happens at this line: `String inputName = keyboard.next();`

For instance, if I were to type `apogee` in your application and then press enter, then `inputName` would be set to `apogee`. It seems great until now, but, the enter key was also considered as an input.

Now, when we arrive at `String inputChoice1 = keyboard.nextLine();`, the enter key would be considered as an input and your `inputChoice1` is now an empty string. Since you have no conditions which matches an empty string, you will exit the application.

There are two ways to solve this issue:

1. Add `keyboard.nextLine()` right after `String inputName = keyboard.next();` to handle the input triggered by the enter key ("\n")
2. Use `keyboard.nextLine()` instead of `next()`

Happy Coding!